# How is the stack clean up value (retn) calculated?

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to learn a little reverse engineering.  I understand the concepts but there are some specifics that I'm having trouble squaring.  The function below is from a file I decided to disassemble and study.  I know it's a __stdcall by the retn but I can't figure out how the 0x1c value is calculated.  This is from IDA and it shows 4 arguments to the function that equal 32 bytes (20h).  Even with the stack space request (sub esp, 10h) in the middle of the function, I'm not see where the retn 1ch is coming from.

```
arg_0           = dword ptr  8
arg_4           = byte ptr  0Ch
arg_14          = dword ptr  1Ch
arg_18          = dword ptr  20h

             mov     edi, edi
             push    ebp
             mov     ebp, esp
             push    esi
             push    edi
             push    dword ptr [ebp+20h]
             mov     eax, [ecx]
             push    [ebp+arg_14]
             lea     esi, [ebp+0Ch]
             push    3
             push    3
             sub     esp, 10h
             mov     edi, esp
             push    dword ptr [ebp+8]
             movsd
             movsd
             movsd
             movsd
             call    dword ptr [eax+18h]
             pop     edi
             pop     esi
             pop     ebp
             retn    1Ch
```

Comment: It forgot to use arg_18, a 4 byte argument.  Passed arguments start at ebp+8 and end at ebp+24h, 24h - 8 = 1Ch.

Comment: this not `__stdcall` function - but `__thiscall` . *ecx* point to class instance (*this*) + 7 args. called virtual function at offset 0x18 in vtable

Comment: `XX::fn(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6 a7)
{
 /*virtual call*/vfn_6(a2, a3, a4, a5, a1, a6);
}`

Comment: You may be misreading the disassembly.  The subscripts of `arg_` are showing the cumulative arg area size, and the values on the right are offsets wrt. `ebp`.  The first arg is at `ebp+0x08`, and the last is `ebp+0x20`.  (Lower offsets are the saved value of `ebp` and the return address.) The difference is 0x18, and the last arg is 4 bytes, so total arg size is 0x1c. That's what's removed by the `retn` instruction after saved registers are popped.